# how to set view pager corresponding in android

Tags: android

this class where am displaying item in listview

```
public class FragHome extends SherlockFragment {
    GlobalData getset;
    private ListView listView;
    EditText contact_editSearch;
    private View root;

    public FragHome() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    String[] itemname = { "होम", "देश समाचार", "छत्तीसगढ़", "विदेश समाचार",
            "कारोबार", "खेल समाचार", "मनोरंजन", "लाइफ" };
    Integer[] imgid = { R.drawable.pic1, R.drawable.pic1, R.drawable.pic1,
            R.drawable.pic1, R.drawable.pic1, R.drawable.pic1, R.drawable.pic1,
            R.drawable.pic1, };

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.frag_home, container, false);
        listView = (ListView) root.findViewById(R.id.contact_listview);

        // this is just dummy data
        getset = new GlobalData(); 
        CustomListAdapter adapter = new CustomListAdapter(getActivity(),
                itemname, imgid);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                    long arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent myint = new Intent(getActivity(), DetailPage.class);
                int pos = arg2;
                getset.setId(String.valueOf(pos));
                startActivity(myint);
            }
        });

        return root;
    }
    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

    }
```

DetailPage class where i am click on item and open page :

```
public class DetailPage extends Activity {
    String[] itemname = { "होम", "देश समाचार", "छत्तीसगढ़", "विदेश समाचार",
            "कारोबार", "खेल समाचार", "मनोरंजन", "लाइफ" };
    Integer[] imgid = { R.drawable.pic1, R.drawable.pic1, R.drawable.pic1,
            R.drawable.pic1, R.drawable.pic1, R.drawable.pic1, R.drawable.pic1,
            R.drawable.pic1, };

    ViewPager viewPager;
    ViewPagerAdapte adapter;
    GlobalData getset;
    String id;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.detailpage);
        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        adapter = new ViewPagerAdapte(DetailPage.this, itemname, imgid);
        getset = new GlobalData();
        id = getset.getId();

        // Binds the Adapter to the ViewPager
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

}
```

here is view pager class:

```
public class ViewPagerAdapte extends PagerAdapter {
    String[] itemname = { "होम", "देश समाचार", "छत्तीसगढ़", "विदेश समाचार",
            "कारोबार", "खेल समाचार", "मनोरंजन", "लाइफ" };
    Integer[] imgid = { R.drawable.pic1, R.drawable.pic1, R.drawable.pic1,
            R.drawable.pic1, R.drawable.pic1, R.drawable.pic1, R.drawable.pic1,
            R.drawable.pic1, };
    Context context;
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    GlobalData getset;

    public ViewPagerAdapte(Context context, String[] itemname, Integer[] imgid) {
        this.context = context;
        this.itemname = itemname;
        this.imgid = imgid;
        getset = new GlobalData();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return itemname.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        TextView txtpopulation;
        ImageView imgflag;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.viewpager_item, container,
                false);
        txtpopulation = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.population);
        txtpopulation.setText(itemname[position]);
        // Locate the ImageView in viewpager_item.xml
        imgflag = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.flag);
        imgflag.setImageResource(imgid[position]);
        ((ViewPager) container).addView(itemView);
        return itemView;

    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return view == ((RelativeLayout) object);
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        // Remove viewpager_item.xml from ViewPager
        ((ViewPager) container).removeView((RelativeLayout) object);

    }
}
```

I able to flip the page but problem i am facing when click on item then it open first page item detail while it should open item number 5. please help me or suggest me i want suppose if click on 5 then detail page should display item5 data and front flip and back flip should work accordingly please suggest me how to implement this .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass pos value through intent

```
    intent.putExtra("position", pos);
```

and get it through

```
id = intent.getIntExtra("position", 0);
```

Just add this line in onCreate method of DetailPage class, just below the setAdapter call

```
viewpager.setCurrentItem(id)
```

Comment: I have use this code but its not working it always start from start 0 index please tell me how to fix

Comment: Log the id value it must be zero

Comment: where it should be Zero  Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
  id= bundle.getInt("id");
  viewPager.setCurrentItem(id);
   viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);   use same code but please help while am getting id 5 when i select 5th item

Comment: add  viewPager.setCurrentItem(id); after viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

Comment: same i have used Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
  id= bundle.getInt("id",0);  same code but not working please look myc ode